# $\lim_{m \to \infty}{\prod_{i=0}^{tm-1}(1+\frac{r(i)}{m})} = e^{\int_{0}^{t} r(s)ds}$?

Tags: analysis, exponential-function

How can I deduce the following equation ?:

$$
\lim_{m \to \infty}\prod_{i = 0}^{{\large tm - 1}}
\left[\,1 + \frac{r\left(\,i\,\right)}{m}\,\right] =
\exp\left(\,\int_{0}^{t}r\left(\,s\,\right)\,\mathrm{d}s\,\right) $$

where $t > 0$ and $r\left(\,i\,\right)$ a real valued function.

I can figure out the series expansion of $\mathrm{e}$, and it makes somehow sense as you can think of $r$ as the average "rate of interest" for example, but what exactly is the math behind it ?.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to put only _mathjax_ in the title, because your post won't show up in any searches and it's not very descriptive of the question. See [how to choose a good title :)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144)

Comment: Will keep this in mind going forward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

There is a suspected typo in the OP.  The argument of $r$ should be $i/m$, not $i$ alone.

Then, we can write

$$\log\left(\prod_{i=0}^{\lfloor tm-1\rfloor} \left(1+\frac{r(i/m)}{m}\right)\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor tm-1\rfloor}  \log\left(1+\frac{r(i/m)}{m}\right)$$

Now use the fact that $\log\left(1+\frac{r(i/m)}{m}\right)=\frac{r(i/m)}{m}+O\left(\frac{r(i/m)}{m}\right)^2$ as $m\to \infty$.

Finish by evaluating the resulting Riemann Sum.